# Nouns ending in "aria" and "eria" – is there a rule?

Tags: português-brasileiro, gramática, ortografia

In Portuguese (Brazil) we have nouns that end in *-aria* and nouns that end in *-eria*. Are there rules / patterns / an etymological explanation of when we use each?

-aria:

- a chapel*aria*
- a estreb*aria*
- a sapat*aria*
- a merce*aria*

-eria:

- a lavand*eria*
- a sorvet*eria*
- a joalh*eria*
- a cafet*eria*

Comment: Those endings are not regularly used in Portugal, but they exist and they *are* correct. We use lavandaria, gelataria, joalharia and cafetaria instead of [lavanderia](https://dicionario.priberam.org/lavanderia), [sorveteria](https://dicionario.priberam.org/sorveteria), [joalheria](https://dicionario.priberam.org/joalheria) e [cafeteria](https://dicionario.priberam.org/cafeteria).

Comment: @Lawrence *de facto* "state of the art" reference for this is ["Gramática Derivacional do Português"](https://bibliotecadigital.ipb.pt/bitstream/10198/13485/3/Gram%C3%A1tica%20Derivacional.pdf). I wanted to write an answer but didn't have the necessary time.

Comment: This *Gramática* is really interesting. It says much about nouns ending in *-aria*, but nothing about nouns ending in *-eria*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Houaiss dictionary has detailed entries for the suffixes *-eria* and *-aria*. The only rule appears to be: wait until usage establishes one form, the other, or both. The form *-aria* is a lot more common; when an *-eria* word exists it usually has an *-aria* twin; some *-eria* words were adapted from or influenced by Spanish *-ería* or French *-erie*, but they have been around since the 15th century. I now quote the Houaiss dictionary (Lisbon, 2002; original abbreviations expanded into full words; English translation below):

> **-aria** *sufixo* importa remontá-lo a duas fontes, *-IA* (ver) e *-EIRO* (ver), donde resultaram *-eria* e este *-aria*, sendo que *-eria* tanto pode ter tido formação portuguesa interna (à analogia e, por vezes, influência do espanhol *-eria* e do francês *-erie*), como pode ter sido desde o início concorrente de *-aria* pelas influências referidas;

The entry goes on to explain that this suffix *-aria* was highly productive, and lists over 300 words, and the list is not exhaustive. I especially resent the omission of *gataria*.

> **-eria** *sufixo* do francês *-erie*, em curso no português já no século XV, vem sendo objeto de rejeição didática purista, mas apresenta certos casos em que o sufixo  *-aria*, ver, canónico poderia ser fonte de ambiguidade, como em *bateria, galeria, sobranceria*; em vários casos são registadas as duas formas, como *amideria/amidaria, bijuteria/bijutaria, bilheteria/bilhetaria, charcuteria/charcutaria, engraxateria/engraxataria, glutoneria/glutonaria, guasqueria/guascaria, grosseria/grossaria, infanteria/infantaria, joalheria/joalharia, leiteria/leitaria, lavanderia/lavandaria, loteria/lotaria, mamposteria/mampostaria, parceria/parçaria, pedanteria/pedantaria, peleria/pelaria, selvageria/selvajaria, sorveteria/sorvetaria, talabarteria/talabartaria, tolderia/toldaria, uisqueria/uiscaria, vozeria/vozaria*; a forma *-eria* é, em certo sentido, coonestada pelo sufixo conexo de agente     *-EIRO*, ver

Again, this list is not exhaustive. In entry *-aria* we can still find (all these have an *-aria* twin): *chocolateria, carniceria, gendarmeria, barganteria, galanteria, guacheria, carroceria*. *Cafeteria* and *cafetaria* don’t appear in either list (they have their own entries though).

### Houaiss entries translated

> **-aria** *suffix* it is important to trace them to two origins, *-IA* (see) and *-EIRO* (see), from which     *-eria* and this *-aria* resulted; *-eria* may have been internally formed in the  Portuguese language (by analogy to and, sometimes, influenced by, Spanish *-ería* and French *-erie*) as well as a competitor from the beginning to *-aria* under the aforementioned influence.
>
> **-eria** *suffix* from French *-erie*, already in use in Portuguese in the 15th century, it keeps being the target of purist, didactical objection, but there are certain cases where the canonical suffix   *-aria*, see, could give rise to ambiguity, as in *bateria, galeria, sobranceria*; in various cases both forms have been recorded [word list];  the form *-eria* is, in some sense, made to look honest/legitimated by the related agency suffix *-EIRO*, see

Comment: Thank you for this! In the cases where the two forms exist, is one more prevalent in Brazilian Portuguese?

Comment: @Lawrence, I'm from Portugal; my hunch is it will depend on the word. I looked up the words Houaiss lists in [Michaelis](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/guacharia/), a Brazilian dictionary, and it has the *-eria* form only or in *-aria* just tells you to look up *-eria* (which I take to mean *-eria* is prevalent) in *bilheteria, bijuteria, carroceria, grosseria, joalheria, leiteria, lavanderia, loteria, parceria, selvageria, sorveteria* [all fairly common words] *uisqueria* [common?], *mamposteria* [had never heard of it]; it's the opposite  with >>

Comment: >> *charcutaria, infantaria* [common words], *chocolataria, galantaria, vozaria* [so-so], *amidaria, carniçaria, gendarmaria, bargantaria, talabartaria, toldaria* [I think all of these are pretty rare]. So if this sample is anything to go by, where a common word has both forms, more often than not, the *-eria* form is more common. Which of course still leaves some where *-aria* is more common. What is clear is that *-eria* words are more common in Brazil than in Portugal. I Portugal we use *grosseria, parceria* (had never heard the other variant); *carroceria, galanteria, bijuteria* >>

Comment: >> compete with the *-aria* form. In all other cases we use only the *-aria* form, except for the rare words, which I have no idea about.

Comment: @bad_coder, não me quere indicar a página? Fiz um busca rápida. Encontrei apenas uma nota sobre *-aria*, mas que não ajuda na questão do *-aria* vs. *-eria*. Creio que as limitações que eles apontam ao *-aria* se aplicam também ao *-eria*.

Comment: @bad_coder, vejo amanhã. Eu faço um Ctr+F -eri, e não há nada!

Comment: Depois amanhã vê o index da página 8 e vês lá essas páginas que indiquei.(Se há livro nos tempos recentes que vale a pena comprar é este. Tb ando curioso para ver a nova gramática da Gulbenkian, poderá ser a melhor de todos os tempos.)

Comment: @bad_coder, Deves ter linkado a gramática errada. Nessas páginas, 200, 226-228, 256, 278, não há nada sobre *-eria*; nem sobre *-aria*.

Comment: Página 7 e 8 é o index na edição em papel, fica página 10 e 11 na edição digital PDF se for esse o número de paginação para onde olhas. Também me enganei nos sufixos, vê páginas 191, 252 da paginação em papel. Estou com falta de tempo, mas parece-me que a última série de exemplos na pergunta usam uma vogal diferente da que é usada em Portugal.

Comment: @bad_coder, eu já tinha visto a p. 191 (pá, procurar no índice foi das primeiras coisas que fiz). É sobre o *-aria*; não menciona sequer o *-eria*. A p. 252 é sobre adjetivos, e não diz nada sobre *-aria* ou *-eria*. Procurei com cuidado no livro todo, e não há nada sobre *-eria*; *-eria* ou *-eri(a)* simplesmente não acorrem no livro. Eu tenho a Gramática do Português. Ainda vou dar uma vista de olhos.

Comment: Também vou ver, mas não prometo nada para esta semana. Tenho a lista de afazeres preenchida no imediato.

Comment: @bad_coder, poupo-te o trabalho: a morfologia vem no volume III, que ainda não foi publicado! Pelo andar da carruagem, não faço quando será.

Comment: Great answer.  I, for one, was never taught any rules.  I simply learned them from usage.

Comment: @Centaurus, very much so: there are no rules. A weak pattern perhaps: the *-eria* words tend to be more common as labels for types of shops and commercial venues.